# ng-view does not seem to be working. Nothing shows up

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-view, angularjs-ng-route

For some reason my ng-view has decided not to work. Its been a bit since I've worked with angular so maybe I'm missing something. On the view *home.html* all it has is text *hello* in an h1 tag but its not showing up.

```js
var mistApp=angular.module('mistApp',['ngRoute']);

mistApp.controller('mainCtrl',function($scope,$http,$route, $routeParams, $location){
 

 //routes
mistApp.config(function($routeProvider,$locationProvider){
 $routeProvider.when('/',{
  templateUrl:'views/home.html',
  controller:'homeCtrl'
 })
 $routeProvider.when('/calendar',{
  templateUrl:'views/calendar.html',
  controller:'calendarCtrl'
 })
 .otherwise({
  redirectTo:'/'
 });


}) //end routes

}) //end of mainCtrl
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="mistApp">
<head>
 <title></title>

 <!-- boostrap -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

 <!-- angular -->
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular-route.js"></script>


 <!-- controllers -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/mainCtrl.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/calendarCtrl.js"></script>






</head>

<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
<!-- NAVBAR -->
<nav class="nav navbar-default">
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="navbar-header">
   <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false" class="navbar-toggle collapsed">
    <span class="sr-only"> Toggle Navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar""></span>
    <span class="icon-bar""></span>
    <span class="icon-bar""></span>
   </button>

   <a href="#/" class="navbar-brand"></a>
   <h3>GameTown</h3>
  </div>
   <div id="navbar-collapse-1" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li>
       <a ng-href="#/">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li ng-hide="loggedIn">
       <a ng-href="#/calendar">Calendar</a>
      </li>
                  <li ng-hide="loggedIn">
                      <a ng-href="#/updates">Updates</a>
                  </li>  
                   
                  <li ng-hide="loggedIn">
                      <a ng-href="#/chat">Chat</a>
                  </li>
                  <li ng-hide="loggedIn">
                      <a ng-href="#/ideas">Ideas</a>
                  </li>                 
     </ul>
   </div> 
 </div>
</nav>

<div id="views" ng-view></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What happens if you move the `mistApp.config` stuff so it is outside of your `mistApp.controller` definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The problem

The module call (i.e. *config()*) for the router is inside the controller callback.

### Solution

Move the module call outside the controller callback. Look at the documentation for [ngRoute](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute) and [the example](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route#example) for more information.

So this:

```
mistApp.controller('mainCtrl',function($scope,$http,$route, $routeParams, $location){
    //routes
    mistApp.config(function($routeProvider,$locationProvider){
    ...
    }) //end routes
}) //end of mainCtrl
```

Becomes:

```
mistApp.controller('mainCtrl',function($scope,$http,$route, $routeParams, $location){
}); //end of mainCtrl

//routes
mistApp.config(function($routeProvider,$locationProvider){
   ...
}) //end routes
```

See it working in [this updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Eu0Ivuj9LSWqRQT4CU8X?p=preview).

One other issue I noticed was invalid HTML. There are three lines in the hamburger menu have an extra double quote after the *class* attribute. So these lines:

```
<span class="icon-bar""></span>
```

should be updated like this:

```
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
```

Instead of those three spans, you could consider using the *glyphicon-menu-hamburger* class name to utilize the Bootstrap menu icon (see the [Components section](http://getbootstrap.com/components/) for more information about those).

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger" aria-hidden="true"></span>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!